# How to "redecorate" windows?

Tags: lxde

I right-clicked the title bar of Rhythmbox and then clicked *Un/Decorate*. Now the title bar is gone. I want it back and I can't figure out how.

I tried hitting <kbd>D</kbd>, but nothing happens.

Comment: What desktop manager(Unity/gnome/kde/others) are you using? I don't see the "Un/decorate" option in rhythmbox.

Comment: I think that's because you're using unity, I'm LXDE and I think it's openbox.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Strangely, by default, there is no toggle to decorate/undecorate a window.

You need to do one of two things:  either define a keybinding to toggle or use the shortcut key to redisplay the window menu.

**Lets examine option 1**

To do this:

1. Open `lxterminal` and run:

   ```
   leafpad ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
   ```
2. Search for the first instance of `<keybinding>`.
3. Then add the following keybinding:

   [image: lubuntu-rc.xml content]

   ```
   <keybind key="W-A-D">
     <action name="ToggleDecorations"></action>
   </keybind>
   ```
4. Now run:

   ```
   openbox --reconfigure
   ```

   to make your changes effective (alternatively, you can logout and login).
5. You'll be able to toggle the decoration using <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

   The Windows key is also another name for <kbd>Meta</kbd>.

---

**Lets also examine option 2**

Thanks to [Glutanimate](https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/glutanimate).

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will display the window submenu where you can select *Un/Decorate*. Obviously this doesn't need a keybinding, but it's nice to have a toggle option to quickly turn the titlebar on/off.

[image: menu showing Un/Decorate option]

Comment: You can also summon the window menu with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default.

Comment: ...I think I'm sticking to option 2. Thanks a lot!!! your answer really hits the spot! :D :D :D

Comment: @Glutanimate It does not seem to work for xclock on lxde.

Comment: option 2 is cool.

Answer (score 5):

I have just managed to invoke the Openbox' context menu on an undecorated window by right-clicking the bottom edge of the window. It's just that you need to right-click as soon as the resize cursor is displayed.
The previous tricks did not work for me because there was a virtual Windows machine inside the window, so it was catching the Alt+space key combination...

Comment: Similarly, you get the Openbox context menu when right-clicking in a maximized window with the mouse pointer hitting the upper screen edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it permanent via configuration file:///~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

```
<applications>  
  <application class="*">
      <maximized>true</maximized>
      <decor>no</decor>
  </application>
</applications>
```

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=82924 (#2)

Comment: The OP already has "un/Decorate" windows and wants the opposite of what you suggest.

Comment: Editing your answer to make it correct would be a good idea

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question but it helped me to figure out how to un-decor permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Right click any window edge or corner or use Alt+Space. By "window edge", I mean the edges you would normally use to resize with a left mouse button drag. In this case, the right click brings up the menu to show or hide window decorations.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. Could you [edit] to expand on the recommendation, perhaps including screenshots showing how a person might “redecorate” their application windows? A more complete answer could help people in the future 

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  It appears that you may have created duplicate accounts; they can be merged following [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts).