# Where has my title bar in Deluge gone?

Tags: gnome, 14.10, deluge

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 with Gnome 3.14 installed from the Gnome and the Gnome staging ppas. I was previously on 14.04 with Gnome 3.12 installed. After the upgrade, I no longer have the title bar in Deluge. Here's an screencap:

[image]

I thought it was maybe a GTK2 issue, but Firefox and Geany both work fine.

Comment: wait for deluge update

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The link you provided did seem to apply only to LXDE/Openbox, but once I started snooping through my `~/.config` folder, I found a deluge config folder.

I removed deluge, deleted the deluge folder from inside `~/.config`, and reinstalled Deluge. Everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally undecorate it? Maybe this only applies to lxde, but have a look to see if it's relevant: [How to "redecorate" windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453953/how-to-redecorate-windows)

Comment: I was thinking maybe it was related to something deluge is doing or trying to do... try this?: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html